# Using protected or public with virtual function?

Tags: c++, public, protected

I always see a lot of examples where virtual functions are declared as protected in header files. Is it wrong to declare virtual functions as public? What is the best practice when using virtual functions?

Comment: If you want it to be called by anyone then `public`. If you want it to be called by any derived class then `protected`. If you want it to be called only by the class itself then `private`. **Note**: a private virtual function can be dispatched from the base class.

Comment: [This](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm) might be an interesting read for you.

Comment: It could be the [Non-Virtual Interface (NVI) idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it wrong to declare virtual functions as public?

No.

> What is the best practice when using virtual functions?

That completely depends on your use cases. The keywords per se are orthogonal in usage.

Sometimes it's good to have `protected` `virtual` functions like with the [template design pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method/cpp/1), most of the time the `virtual` functions are declared `public` to provide an interface.

There are two design pattern categories the `public` and `protected` inheritance fall into:

1. Template function pattern:

   ```
   class Base {
   public:
       void foo() {
           bar();
       };
   protected:
       virtual void bar() = 0;
   };

   class Implementation : public Base {
        void bar() {
            // provide the implementation
        }
   };
   ```
2. Interface pattern:

   ```
   struct Interface {
       virtual void foo() = 0;
       virtual ~Interface() {}
   };

   class Implementation : public Interface {
   public:
        void foo() {
            // provide the implementation
        }
   };
   ```

---

There are other design patterns, that may omit `virtual` at all (see [CTRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)), but the semantics of `public` and `protected` are still kept.

Comment: Sometimes they aren't directly accessible to support the NVI idiom.